# Is it possible to specify an url as a path for saveAs() function in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

```
Sub Créerunduplica()

Dim extension As String
Dim chemin As String, nomfichier As String
Dim style As Integer

extension = ".xlsm"
chemin = "D:\NAP\04-Dossiers clients\"
nomfichier = ActiveSheet.Range("b1") & "_" & Range("b3") & "_" & Range("d3") & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd hh""h""mm") & "_Calcul corp" & extension

    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=chemin & nomfichier
    End With
End Sub
```

This code saves the file in "chemin" (path) which is a local path but i want it to save the file in google drive.

Is this possible? How to do it?

Comment: Just a path? How would you prevent everyone on the internet from being able to overwrite it?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

Answer (score 0):

I have done it but with OneDrive, which has an application that is installed and is like a local directory on your pc, I think Drive, also an application that is like a local directory, you would only have to use the directory that has that folder and it would be loaded into that folder and then it syncs, it's not very effective, but it can.

Comment: What I did is that in OneDrive, I recorded a macro and saved the book in the folder in which it synchronized and from that code I extracted the URL, in some cases it was a URL in another Address like the ones written in local folders .